# Opening .csv in excel deletes content following a semi-colon

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a DataFrame in Python, with several columns containing textual data. In some columns, there is a semi-colon present in the cell. For instance:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| veel doden | Medisch: mensen met een beperking |
| de woonzorgcentra; de rusthuizen | Socio-economisch: zorgsector |

If I convert the DataFrame to a .csv file, this works fine, using

```
data.to_csv(path_data, sep=`\t`)
```

If I open the csv file in VSCode, all data is still present. However, if I download the file and open it in excel, all content that follows the semi-colon seems to have disappeared. It looks like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| veel doden | Medisch: mensen met een beperking |
| de woonzorgcentra |  |

Can someone explain to me why this happens? Thanks a lot!

I tried changing the separator when saving the .csv file and consulted the documentation of pandas.DataFrame.to_csv , but I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: When you are importing file in excel do you have defined `;` as column separator? Disable it and use only tab `\t` in importing window.
...Or maybe excel thinks that `;` is cell formula separator?

Comment: Hi, yes, I only have the tab separator!